# Can a class library read the app.config file of a Coded UI Test that is being executed?

Tags: c#, app-config, coded-ui-tests

I've developed a little utility library that deals with a lot of the configuration and logging needed to by all of my Coded UI test projects.  I have the class library set up to read the app.config file using the following to read the values:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"]
```

I understand that when you include this class library in another project, the app.config of the new project should be used during execution.  Actually, that's precisely what I want, it just doesn't appear to be happening.

My other project is a CUIT but it seems as though my class library it includes isn't reading any sort of app.config.  Not its own, not the CUIT's.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing the following line in my class library.  After adding it things worked as I expected.

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```